# ARCGIS Calculate Value Tool - Always returns same value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I want to check if an environmental shapefile was generated from a previous process.

I utilized the Calculate Value tool in Modelbuilder but the problem is that no matter if this Wetlands layer exists or not, it always returns "true". I've tested the code in IDLE and it runs with no issues.

**Expression**

> x("%Wetlands%", "%Workspace%")

**Code Block**

```py
import arcpy
def x(Wetlands, Workspace): 
 arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Omitted/Environmental.gdb"
 if arcpy.Exists("Wetlands"):
   return "true"
 else:
   return "false"
```

**Data type**

> Boolean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should this line:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Omitted/Environmental.gdb"
```

not be:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = Workspace
```

and this line:

```
if arcpy.Exists("Wetlands"):
```

be:

```
if arcpy.Exists(Wetlands):
```